# How do I output % in the last row?

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio..h>
 main() {
int a,b;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
printf("%d - %d = %d\n", a, b, a-b);
printf("%d / %d = %d\n", a, b, a/b);
printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, b, a*b);
printf("%d % %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
}
```

If you look at the last line in this code, you want to print%, but% does not.
Please let me know if %% is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can print a literal `%` using `%%`.

C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §7.21.6.1 8:

> `%`
>
> A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
>   conversion specification shall be `%%`.